# Datamapper equivalent of SQL Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

I have a Trees Class in my rails application. In there I have a field called 'leaves'. Now for a certain operation, I need to execute the following SQL command with a bitwise & operation under condition.

```
SELECT * FROM trees WHERE (leaves & 6) = 6
```

How do I do it using datamapper ? I do not want to do it in the below way :

```
repository(:default).adapter.select('SELECT * FROM trees WHERE (leaves & 6) = 6')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:conditions`.

```
Tree.all(:conditions => ['(leaves & ?) = ?', 6, 6])
```